# Cookies are not saved in Safari

Tags: reactjs, express, safari, jwt, passport.js

i'm facing this issue where safari doesn't save my refreshToken in my cookies. It's working in Chrome and FF. Cookies are enabled in Safari. This is the response i'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: refreshToken=s%3AeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTlmN2UwNGNjZmIyYzVmNjAzMWQ2NDciLCJpYXQiOjE2NDIxMDY4NjQsImV4cCI6MTY0NDY5ODg2NH0.ERJ-hJAcBtuYkLJRzRBOyURJJi_jUR6fdbB23efH5VQ.5QrtzGP6hmvQ7lU9wQSwTa9D3HfKZZ5WOHxOpPX4xV4; Max-Age=2592000; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 12 Feb 2022 20:47:44 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
ETag: W/"c7-H0SVQT/Xk+Keg7rMoBmrEtlM5Hw"
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:47:44 GMT
Vary: Origin
Content-Length: 199
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
X-Powered-By: Express
```

i'm using safari 15. The backend that is sending the cookie in express and these are the routes and the cookie options:

```
router.post('/refreshToken', (req, res, next) => {
  const { signedCookies = {} } = req;
  const { refreshToken } = signedCookies;

  if (refreshToken) {
    try {
      const payload = jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
      const userId = payload._id;
      User.findOne({ _id: userId }).then(
        (user) => {
          if (user) {
            // Find the refresh token against the user record in database
            const tokenIndex = user.refreshToken.findIndex(
              (item) => item.refreshToken === refreshToken
            );

            if (tokenIndex === -1) {
              res.statusCode = 401;
              res.send('Unauthorized');
            } else {
              const token = getToken({ _id: userId });
              // If the refresh token exists, then create new one and replace it.
              const newRefreshToken = getRefreshToken({ _id: userId });
              user.refreshToken[tokenIndex] = { refreshToken: newRefreshToken };
              user.save((err, user) => {
                if (err) {
                  res.statusCode = 500;
                  res.send(err);
                } else {
                  res.cookie('refreshToken', newRefreshToken, COOKIE_OPTIONS);
                  res.send({ success: true, token });
                }
              });
            }
          } else {
            res.statusCode = 401;
            res.send('Unauthorized');
          }
        },
        (err) => next(err)
      );
    } catch (err) {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.send('Unauthorized');
    }
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.send('Unauthorized');
  }
});
```

CookieOptions

```
httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  signed: true,
  maxAge: eval(process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY) * 1000,
  sameSite: 'none',
```

Answer (score 0):

By default safari have disabled cross-domain cookies(some security reasons). You must enable it in settings or you need to came up with different solution

Comment: All Cookies are allowed in my Browser Settings + prevent cross Site tracking is disabled. Any Change you know where to enable the setting in the browser?
thanks for your help.